# Installing apache and mod_wsgi for django web application?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

So I have been struggling with installing apache and mod_wsgi so I can deploy my web application. I have been trying to follow this guide:

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide

but I am still having troubles with finding and installing the apache and mod_wsgi packages. There appears to be many many places you can install these things online and I don't know which ones to choose. Could I get some help with this?

I am using Ubuntu so I need Apache 2.2 with the dev package.

My python setup should be fine. In the link above when I get to the configure part I get the error...

```
checking Apache version... ./configure: line 2765: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2765: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2766: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2769: /: Is a directory

checking for python... /home/joe/Documents/virtualenvs/exchange/bin/python
./configure: line 2964: apxs: command not found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

So it appears I did not install apache correctly initially and that is why I am looking for help.

Thanks!

Comment: Check these links to refer: django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ and this link too https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Yeah I was following the django one, but Im stuck at configuration and installation haha. Ill check out the second one now though.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile either of these from source? Get  then from the Ubuntu package: `sudo apt-get install apache libapache2-mod-wsgi`.

Comment: I was looking for the Ubuntu package's but had trouble finding them for some reason... That second link was helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to find where Apache installed `apxs`. Once you know the location (in this case, assuming it is `/usr/sbin/apxs`):

```
./configure --enable-apache2=/usr/sbin/apxs
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you recommend to find my apxs folder?

Comment: (Clarification: I am on Mac)

Comment: Assuming you've got Apache installed, `find / -name "apxs"`; you may have to use `sudo` to run it as root.